# Looking for a letter exchange between Zen Teacher and (female?) student

Tags: reference-request

a few months ago I looked up one of the questions, and there was a link to a specific letter exchange. However, no matter where I look here or on search engines, I can't find it. If I'm not mistaken, it was between a female student and a Zen teacher/master.

The student was terminally ill, but managed to attain higher forms of consciousness/enlightenment. Shortly after she attained enlightenment, she felt that she was dying and informed the Zen teacher of this, who then came in the last few days of her life to pay a visit.

The Zen teacher then published this letter exchange, where he also made notes on the letters, explaining how she developed further and further.

Does anyone know about this and can post a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link again: [Yaeko Iwasaki´s Enlightenment Letters to Harada-Roshi and his Comments](https://sites.google.com/site/esabsnichtenglisch/yaeko-iwasaki-s-enlightenment-letters-to-harada-roshi-and-his-comments)

This is published in *The Three Pillars of Zen*.